# ERROR: Error:(3, 10) 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am using Android studio 2.2.3 and OpenCV 3.1.0. i resolved many errors but could not find solution for this one.

This is my Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ahmedarif.fyp3"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "C:\\Android\\sdk1\\ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
    }
}
```

[image]

I also tried buigl.gradle from [ph0b](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/)

but that build.gradle showing error about ndk-bulid.cmd. I tried almost every thing but didn't work for me. help to get rid of this. Tahnx

Answer (score 1):

[image]

And then my build.gradle ;

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.c.a.engineer.imageprocessingpre"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs' } }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
}
```

It's work for me. You can try this. And I developed image processing app. This my app screenshot;

[image]

Comment: did you use NDK?? because in build.gradle you must have to give ndk path and some .mk file

Comment: No. I didnt use NDK. But its work. You should try that. I wanted to show another way. I thought maybe i can help.

Comment: i think you cannot use native function with out ndk.

Comment: does your project have any .h or .cpp file?

Comment: Yes i have .hpp file but this path OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include\opencv2

Comment: then i have imported project. Anyway i watched this video and i tried.

Comment: i also follow these tutorials :) i am having trouble in facedetection one

Comment: i have solved this. just use android built in support for c and c++

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of android studio just use its built in support for c and c++ from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)
And i am usnig the same build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ahmedarif.fyp3"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "C:\\Android\\sdk1\\ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
    }
}
```